# NSDateFormatter is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My `NSDateFormatter` is providing a default date of

> 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

where i need it to format in the format of  `Mon, 24 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST`

please find my code for your reference:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZZ'"];
event.startDate = [formatter1 dateFromString:self.eventtime];
```

where as `self.eventtime` is Mon, 24 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST

Comment: Put the exact self.eventtime string in your question.  I am almost positive your format string doesn't match the date string you are trying to use.

Comment: edited the question, it is Mon, 24 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST.

Comment: Your format string doesn't match, as I expected.  Did you just copy and paste it from somewhere?

Comment: @borrrden: every thing works fine. self.eventtime is notworking for date from string, but works when i do NSLog!!!!!

Comment: Of course it is not working...because you are trying to parse with with a format string **that doesn't match**, as I said.  For example, notice the `.SSS` in the middle?  That means it is expecting milliseconds in the string but your string has none.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; 
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter1 stringFromDate:date]);
```

Output:

> Fri, 14 Dec 2012 06:43:44 GMT

Answer (score 0):

try this bellow code...

```
    NSString *str = @"2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Also see my blog for more information about `NSDate` class and Formats ..[My Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html)